# Invalid content error with https:inbound-endpoint

Tags: mule

When using this XML

```xml
<https:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="${sso.ezwim.host}" port="${sso.ezwim.port}" path="${sso.ezwim.path}" doc:name="SSO Entry Point" method="POST" connector-ref="httpsConnector">
    <http:body-to-parameter-map-transformer />
    <response>
        <message-properties-transformer>
            <add-message-property key="Content-Type" value="text/html"/>
        </message-properties-transformer>
    </response>
</https:inbound-endpoint>
```

I receive the following error:

> Invalid content was found starting with element 'https:inbound-endpoint'. One of `{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-processor,     "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-outbound-endpoint, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":response, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-exception-strategy, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-info-mapping}` is expected.

What does this error mean and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the mule-transport-http JAR on the classpath: it's as if it is not.

Also ensure the namespace definition is compatible with the version of Mule you are using. You may have defined the namespace for version 3.3 and be on 3.4. It's better to use `current` anyway, as shown here:

```
xmlns:https="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https"

xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https
                    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https/current/mule-https.xsd"
```

Comment: Maybe a version mismatch then? See my revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its the Eclipse's default schema validation settings.

See http://blogs.mulesoft.org/overcoming-xml-validation-errors-in-eclipse-35/

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared `https` prefix, like this:

```
<mule xmlns:https="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https" 

xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https
```

Comment: Yes i find error. It was erorr in proccessor-chain right before inbound-endpoint block.